# updating the input layer of a neural networks in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, keras-layer

I have a network with two input layers, the first one is an image data ( e.g. MNIST) and the second one is an auxiliary vector,

```
A_vec = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (1, n_d))
A_vec1=np.tile(A_vec, (size_1, 1))

image_inputs = Input(shape=(original_dim,),name='Image_Inputs')
A_inputs = Input(shape=(n_d,),name='A_Inputs')
inputs = keras.layers.concatenate([image_inputs, A_inputs],name='Inputs')
```

#### .......intermediate layers......

```
Image_Outputs= Dense(
original_dim,
activation='sigmoid',
name='Image_Outputs')(intermediate layers)

A_Outputs= Dense(
    n_d,
    activation='sigmoid',
    name='A_Outputs')(intermediate layers)

outputs = keras.layers.concatenate([Image_Outputs, A_Outputs],name='Outputs')
```

Here, the `A_vec`in the initialization for `A_inputs`. But, I want to update it in each epoch by using the `A_Outputs`. I mean after the first iteration, I need to use the estimated values for `A_Outputs` as the updated values of the`A_inputs` in the second epochs and same prcedure for next epochs. Is there any way to do that in *Tensorflow*, *Keras* or *pytorch*?